# Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, serialization, flutter-web

I am new to flutter and I am developing a web app using flutter Web and RESTful API for backend. Am trying to make a get Request, however I am getting an error "Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type List",which have tried to debug based on the suggestions found here on stackOverflow but I can't seem to solve this issue. Here is a screenshot of the error am getting:
[image]

My API Response looks like this

```css
{
  "page": 1,
  "pages": 1,
  "pageSize": 20,
  "totalRows": 3,
  "estates": [ {
    "id": "ccd442ae-471b-44c6-9eb3-e3c1dccab9f1",
    "name": "sarova group of hotels",
    "description": "An excuisite provider of luxury hotels and state–of–the–art apartments and villas.",
    "rating": 4,
    "city": {
      "id": "1a861a5a-e793-45cb-9a41-71c5b538da05", "name": "mogadishu", "country": "somalia", "countryISO": "so", "latitude": -1.286389, "longitude": 35.817223, "picture": "https://images.adsttc.com/media/images/5016/4cd3/28ba/0d14/1600/0340/slideshow/stringio.jpg"
    }
    ,
    "startingPricePerNight": 0,
    "checkInTime": "00:00:00",
    "checkOutTime": "00:00:00",
    "isVerified": false,
    "estateGroups": []
  }
  ,
  ]
}
```

And my API Response looks like this

```js
Future < List < EstateSearch >> search(searchText, destination, rating, checkinDate,
  checkoutDate, adult, child, infant, rooms, travelPurpose, page) async {
  var searchUrl =
    "${ApiEndPoint.baseUrl}/estate?q=$searchText&dest_type=$destination&rating=$rating&checkin_date=$checkinDate&checkout_date=$checkoutDate&no_adults=$adult&no_children=$child&no_infant=$infant&no_rooms=$rooms&travel_purpose=$travelPurpose&page=$page";
  http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(searchUrl),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  );
  // print('ResonseBody' + '${response.body}');
  List < EstateSearch > estateList = [];
  var estates =
    (jsonDecode(response.body) as Map < String, dynamic > )["estates"];
  estateList = estates.map((i) => EstateSearch.fromJson(i)).toList();
  return estateList;
}
```

And the serialized model looks like this

```js
class EstateSearch extends Paginator {
  String id;
  String name;
  String description;
  int rating;
  City city;
  double startingPricePerNight;
  String checkInTime;
  String checkOutTime;
  bool isVerified;
  EstateGroup estateGroups;

  EstateSearch({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.rating,
    required this.city,
    required this.startingPricePerNight,
    required this.checkInTime,
    required this.checkOutTime,
    this.isVerified = false,
    required this.estateGroups,
  });
  factory EstateSearch.fromJson(Map < String, dynamic > json) =>
    _$EstateSearchFromJson(json);
  Map < String, dynamic > toJson() => _$EstateSearchToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: Seems like the factory constructor receives a List instead of a map.
Could you check with debugger, what data type is passed to the constructor on runtime.
Is it possible it's a list of Maps?

Comment: @Csisanyi, yes the constructor is receiving a list instead of a map, how can I rectify this so it receives a map

Answer (score 1):

try this for the return value on service

```
final data = json.decode(response.body);
return List<EstateSearch>.from(data['estates'].map((item) => EstateSearch.fromJson(item)));
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it returns the same error as my solution above. Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Answer (score 1):

I identified the mistake was in my model class(EstateSearch), where I was passing estateGroups of type "EstateSearch",whereas the API response was returning a List of estateGroups. So I only had to change the Model to this:

```js
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class EstateSearch extends Paginator {
  String id;
  String name;
  String description;
  int rating;
  City city;
  double startingPricePerNight;
  String checkInTime;
  String checkOutTime;
  bool isVerified;
  List estateGroups = []; // replaced "EstateGroup estateGroups"

  EstateSearch({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.rating,
    required this.city,
    required this.startingPricePerNight,
    required this.checkInTime,
    required this.checkOutTime,
    this.isVerified = false,
    required this.estateGroups,
  });
  factory EstateSearch.fromJson(Map < String, dynamic > json) =>
    _$EstateSearchFromJson(json);
  Map < String, dynamic > toJson() => _$EstateSearchToJson(this);
}
```