# Can't map a JSON response to a class object in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, http-get

Here is yet another "Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List'" questions. My apologies, I've scoured almost every StackOverflow post on the subject including the following:

- [How to fix Flutter Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631068/how-to-fix-flutter-expected-a-value-of-type-mapstring-dynamic-but-got-one)
- [How to fix: value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72573951/how-to-fix-value-of-type-mapstring-dynamic-but-got-one-of-type-listdyna)
- [Flutter: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70909087/flutter-expected-a-value-of-type-mapstring-dynamic-but-got-one-of-type-l)
- [Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69214075/expected-a-value-of-type-mapstring-dynamic-but-got-one-of-type-listdynam)

I've also tried to follow this [Flutter cookbook example](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing).

So, I want to simply call an API that returns a JSON list of lists.  Each one of those inner lists of strings corresponds to a class object I've defined below called 'Provider'. I have created class factory methods to map the JSON to my 'Provider' class:

- `factory Provider.fromJsonMap(Map<String, dynamic> json)   # The preferred way to call`
- `factory Provider.fromJsonListDynamic(List<dynamic> json)`

I would prefer to use the first factory method, rather than the second, because I would like to reference each string by it's name, not an array index as you will see in the code.

**UPDATE:**

As @OmiShah pointed out, the serialized JSON I was passing back from my python API had no schema, so my deserialized JSON response contains no information about the data. So I couldn't make references to the data like so:

```
json["name"]
```

So I changed my python API to serialize a list of strongly typed class objects and pass that I back to flutter as JSON.  Here is a sample of what that data looks like now in python before it's passed back to flutter:

```
[
    Provider(name='Google Translate API', id='google.translate_api.v3', img_url='ggl.png'),
    Provider(name='Microsoft Translator', id='microsoft.translator.v3', img_url='mcs.png'),
    Provider(name='Amazon Translate API', id='amazon.translate.api.v2', img_url='aws.png'),
]
```

And this is what that data looks like after it's deserialized by flutter:

```
final List<dynamic> listProviders = jsonDecode(response.body);

// contents of listProviders
[
    "Provider(name='Google Translate API', id='google.translate_api.v3', img_url='ggl.png')",
    "Provider(name='Microsoft Translator', id='microsoft.translator.v3', img_url='mcs.png')",
    "Provider(name='Amazon Translate API', id='amazon.translate.api.v2', img_url='aws.png')",
]
```

I then cast it as list of maps (listMap) and then attempt to map each object to my 'Provider' class object (providerMap) and finally I convert providerMap to a list:

```
final List<dynamic> listProviders = jsonDecode(response.body);
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> listMap = listProviders.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
var providerMap = listMap.map<Provider>((json) => Provider.fromJsonMap(json));
List<Provider> providers = providerMap.toList();
```

I get the following error when I attempt to convert it to a list:

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'String'
```

I'm at my wit's end with this. I am relatively new to flutter. I would like to pass data around as strongly typed objects and I want to do it in a way that makes sense. Any feedback on this is appreciated.  Below is my code.

The custom class object I created:

```
class Provider
{
    final String name;
    final String id;
    final String imageUrl;

    Provider( {required this.name, required this.id, required this.imageUrl });

    // Calling this function fails 
    factory Provider.fromJsonMap(Map<String, dynamic> json)
    {
        Provider provider = Provider
        (           
            name:     json["name"]     as String,
            id:       json["id"]       as String,
            imageUrl: json["imageUrl"] as String,
        );

        return provider;
    }

    // Calling this function works
    factory Provider.fromJsonListDynamic(List<dynamic> json)
    {
        Provider provider = Provider
        (
            name:     json[0] as String,
            id:       json[1] as String,
            imageUrl: json[2] as String,
        );

        return provider;
    }
}
```

And it's called in this Future async function in a PageState class:

```
class _DetectorPageState extends State<DetectorPage>
{
    ...

    Future<List<Provider>> getMtProviders() async 
    {
        Uri url = Uri.parse(SOME_API_URL);
        http.Response response = await http.get(url);

        if (response.statusCode == 200) 
        {
            // THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK
            final List<dynamic> listProviders = jsonDecode(response.body);
            final List<Map<String, dynamic>> listMap = listProviders.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
            var providerMap = listMap.map<Provider>((json) => Provider.fromJsonMap(json));
            List<Provider> providers = providerMap.toList();
        
            // THIS CODE WORKS
            // List<dynamic> listProviders = jsonDecode(response.body);
            // List<Provider> providers = listProviders.map((provider) => Provider.fromJsonListDynamic(provider as List<dynamic>)).toList();

            return providers;
        } 
        else 
        {
            print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
            return [];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: because ``json["name"] `` and so on doesn't exits! There is no value with those keys in your JSON which is why it gets failed !

Comment: @OMiShah, thanks for pointing that out! As I inspect the JSON that is returned from the API, that is a GLARING oversight that I missed.  Why doesn't flutter/dart catch this?  Why can't I step thru the Provider.fromJsonMap factory method to see what's going on?  So, the problem is with the API code returning the JSON.  I'm not naming objects and properties there.

Comment: @OMiShah, so in essence what I should be doing is serializing my list of objects in my python API code in such a way that includes the schema.  So each object should be a class object.

Comment: @OMiShah, I made sure to include the schema of the data when I serialize the JSON in my python API, but I still get that "Expected a value of type... " error.  I've updated my question to reflect that.  Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the JSON serialization in my python API. I need to serialize a list of dictionary objects that contain my data and not serialize a list of custom class objects.

```
providers_dict = \   # Sample Data
[
    {"name": "Google Translate API", "id": "google.translate_api.v3", "img_url": "ggl_translate.png"},
    {"name": "Microsoft Translator", "id": "microsoft.translator.v3", "img_url": "mcs_translate.png"},
    {"name": "Amazon Translate API", "id": "amazon.translate.api.v2", "img_url": "aws_translate.png"},
]
```

Then you call the json.dumps method to serialize the data into JSON like so:

```
providers_json = json.dumps(providers_dict)
return providers_json
```